# "Lock Function" how can I write it with cosine and sine functions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, problem-solving

I'm a math student currently facing the following dilemma: finding the values for a function. The problem seemed easy but I don't even know how to call it properly, but I believe it can be written as a sum of sine and cosine functions.

For the problem:
Imagine you have a useless lock with 1 digit, it has 5 numbers written on it: 5,4,3,2 and 1; The function begins without you rotating the digit and with the number 5 (point: 5,0), after rotating the lock once the number in display is 4 (point: 4,1), repeat the process 3 (point: 3,2), 2 (point: 2,3), 1 (point: 1,4) until it goes back to 5 (point: 5,6).

How can I write this as a function?

Comment: Should the last point be $(5,5)$? In any case, there are infinitely many functions that pass through a finite number of points.

Comment: @GregMartin , Unfortunatelyn, no. The function should keep going with this sequence, it is something similar to Delta Cephei's Luminosity-Time relationship graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A model of the form

$ a \cos \left(b+\frac{2 \pi  t}{5}\right)+c \cos \left(d+\frac{4 \pi  t}{5}\right)+e \cos \left(f+\frac{6 \pi  t}{5}\right)+g \cos \left(h+\frac{8 \pi  t}{5}\right)+3 $

where a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h are parameters

will fit to the solution:

$ 0.412713 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  t}{5}+0.227908\right)+0.789855 \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  t}{5}+0.514379\right)+0.778897 \cos \left(\frac{6 \pi  t}{5}+1.15817\right)+1.58662 \cos \left(\frac{8 \pi  t}{5}+1.18438\right)+3 $

which repeats as desired.

[image]